# Вопрос про оптимизацию кода

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, замыкания, google-closure

Сегодня попробовал google closure. 
Заметил, что цифры в условиях он ставит на первое место:

Оригинал

```
A.keyLis.blockCtrlAlt.fined(e.keyCode) !== -1 && e.ctrlKey
```

После closure

```
-1 !== A.keyLis.blockCtrlAlt.fined(a.keyCode) && a.ctrlKey
```

Вопрос следующий- как это оптимизирует код?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нет, это не оптимизация. Это [Йода стайл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B). Когда то он помогал избежать ошибок.

Если вместо `a == 1` написать `a = 1`, то будет немного не то, что ожидается, но многие старый компиляторы/интерпретаторы пропускали. А вот так `1 = a` сразу ошибка.

Сейчас многие компиляторы/интерпретаторы умеют "видеть" код вида `a=1` в условиях и ругаются. Как по мне, то сейчас так уже писать не нужно.